# Using different 'missing tile' image for OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to use a different image for missing tiles with an OpenLayers application. Currently the tile is red/pink, with a red x in the upper left corner. I would like to remove that corner.

Does anybody know how to specify this image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```js
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function(){
     this.src = "images/blank.png";
};
```

Comment: Should I add this to Openlayers.js or to the <script> section of the HTML file hosting the Openlayers code?

Comment: to the <script> section of the HTML file hosting the Openlayers code. Actually at the beginning before you do `var map =...`

Answer (score -1):

you can identify tile name from clicked coordinate with some code.  if your problem is not contain big field you can use [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) site for identifying the defective tiles.

and [Google Javascript Api](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html) can help you for finding some trick for this.

Briefly your following way is:

1. LatLontoMeters
2. MeterstoPixel
3. PixeltoTile

Third item will give you the result.

Comment: My issue is not about the actual tile (I have a special set for a given dataset), however sometimes I see missing tile in the corner of my screen, that I wish to replace with some special 'empty' tile